# Disable a drop down list based on the selection of above drop down list in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

Currently I'm having a two drop down list one indicating the role and other assigning to filed. My code is

```
<div class="field">
    <% f.label :role %>
    <%= f.select :role, options_for_select(%w(Investigator Manager Director)) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <h4>Assigning to</h4>
    <%= f.collection_select( :assigned_to, User.find_all_by_role("Manager"), :id, :email)  %>
</div>
```

I want the second drop down list to be appeared only when an investigator is selected in the first drop down list. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use jquery and javascript to accomplish this. Another great resource would be this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) by ryan bates about the exact issue.

What you basically want to do is have some javascript that is observing the current value of the `:role` drop down box. Normally you would do the check through a `.bind (.on)` to the change event of the drop down. Then you want to show/hide the `:assigned_to` box depending on that value. Since this appears to be a stack set of options, it should be a pretty simple bit of javascript.

```
jQuery ->
  ($ 'select#assigned_to').hide()
  ($ 'select#role').change ->
    role = ($ 'select#role :selected').text()
    if role is 'Investigator'
      ($ 'select#assigned_to').show()
```

Now obviously that was coffeescript and should be converted accordingly, but that should help you figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: "Now obviously that was coffeescript and should be converted accordingly"  As I stated. Yes, thats coffeescript. Also, thank you for pointing that out, my indentation freaked out after posting. its fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

i was in a similar situation recently, though im sure your problem has been solved already, i think this will still help to others whom might be seeking answers to the same.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    prevOrigin = "";
    prevDestination = "";
    $('#origin').change(function() {
        var selected = $(":selected",this).text();
        $('#destination option:contains("' + prevOrigin +'")').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#destination option:contains("' + selected +'")').attr("disabled","disabled");
        prevOrigin = selected;
    });

    $('#destination').change(function() {
        var selected = $(":selected",this).text();
        $('#origin option:contains("' + prevDestination +'")').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#origin option:contains("' + selected +'")').attr("disabled","disabled");
        prevDestination = selected;
    });
});​
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jaosimt/zgjgX/4/)